# Computer crashes if left unattended AND running uTorrent, what could be?

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, utorrent

I have a weird problem in which, if I leave my computer unattended, AND I leave uTorrent open, downloading/seeding, the computer simply crashes after about 20 / 30 minutes (don't know exactly since if I leave it, and come back later, it has already restarted or has a BSOD.)

If I leave the computer alone for undefined time WITHOUT uTorrent, nothing happens, and if I am constantly using the computer while using uTorrent, no problem either (I could be using it all day with uT open and it doesn't crash).

So what could it be that the combination of those cases makes the computer crash?

I have already checked the power management so the computer never enters stand by mode, sleep, hibernate, etc. (the only thing I do is turn off the display).

A first guess is that maybe one of my external hard drives DO sleep or enters in a "low power" mode or something if I don't use the PC. but since uT is running MAYBE tries to use that drive, and makes it crash. Could that be possible?

How to know for sure if the external drive does that, and to prevent it from doing so.

Any more ideas of what may be causing that?

Specs:
Windows 7 Pro, 64-bit, 2 GB RAM.
Latest version of uTorrent (although it has been happening for a while now).

UPDATE:

i just found out that uTorrent has Disk cache options ( preferences - advanced - disk cache ). I have no idea if that may be causing problems with my external drive, hence causing the crash.

Comment: Need to know what the BSOD says really, a screenshot or something ...

Comment: Go to System Properties -> Advanced -> Startup and Recovery -> Settings, and turn off "Automatically restart" under "System failure".  This way, you can see the BSOD instead of having the computer just restart itself.  Also, ensure your memory is okay (ensure the computer passes [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)).

Comment: ok, next time BSOD happens, i'll try to get a picture, or write down the info of the it (cuz afaik, a print screen obviously wont work, lol) Or does windows keep the BSOD info anywhere i could check?... I also will try that Memtest. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest going to Control Panel --> System & Security --> Administrative Tools --> Event Viewer, and looking in the Windows Logs, I believe the System and also Application logs will give you a better idea of what may be crashing the system. Look for the Red Exclamation point under the Level category called Error.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off hibernate and power save mode is a good idea for troubleshooting. The next thing to do is to check the event logs and post those details. If it doesn't capture any events before the crash, then you may need to look at the [crash dump](https://superuser.com/search?q=minidump).

Otherwise, I would try the following:

- upgrade uTorrent
- try a different network adapter (or check for updated drivers)
- see if disabling all torrents makes any difference
- if that stops the crashes, then enable them one at a time, and see if the location of the torrent makes any difference

I once had a problem with uTorrent crashing (though Windows 7 didn't crash), but it only happened when the torrents were saved to a specific drive (a portable laptop drive).

Answer (score 0):

You may have the 'Automatic reboot after your download finishes' option selected. Depending on the version of uTorrent, you should be able go to Options and deselect the automatic reboot option.

Comment: thanks, i've checked, but thats not the case. In fact, even if i had it, the pc crashes no matter if a download finishes or is in process. Besides, i also have the option "prevent standby if there are active torrents", so that is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

This used to happen to me too but if you run utorrent and then open up gamebooster http://thepiratebay.sx/torrent/7341306/_Game_Booster_3.5_Beta_2012_XDrone
and click boost it should be fine.
My computer has stopped crashing and it can go for a couple of day no problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please Ensure that your firewall is turned on. If not Try turning on the firewall and let us know what happens.

Comment: Please don't post a comment as an answer. Read [answer] before answering. Thank you!